# JS window. changes to wnd.fe

Tags: javascript

We use webnode for our project and we need to acces the URL params with the JS, but when the code is loaded from the webnode server it contains wnd.fe. instead of window.
Is there any way to prevent it from happening or is there any alternative to get URL params?

Created code which is saved as html snippet in webnode:

```
<div id="text"></div>
<script>

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if (urlParams.get('collection') == 'zastery'){
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = `Text to show`;
}else{
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = ''
}
</script>
```

Code loaded when accesing site from web browser:

```
<div id="text"></div>
<script>

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(wnd.fe.Location.search);

if (urlParams.get('collection') == 'zastery'){
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = `Text to show`;
}else{
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = ''
}
</script>
```

Comment: `window.location.search` cannot be deleted and it is always accessible, why is it causing problems? What are you attempting to do? Be more descriptive with your problem

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina My guess its that some cheap/free hosting who overrides the source code and manipulate it to change the behavior, .e.g display adds or so. If thats true, switch to a different Hoster or pay for it. Or use some dynamic pseudo "encryption" to hide the real object you are trying to access. E.g. ```window[`${atob("bG9jYXRpb24=")}`].search```

Comment: I tried the previous comment without success so I tried to import the script as resource from github `<script></script>` and I got CORB error. Can I somehow import the script from github or somewhere else without getting it blocked?